# bash script , echo output in box

Tags: shell-script, printf, tput

I have created this function, which prints the output as seen in the example image. But, the implementation of this function seems too complex.

Is there a way that I can improve it or implement an alternative solution?

[image: This is an example of the output after executing the "box_out" function with the string argument 'Love Unix & Linux']

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
function box_out() {
    input_char=$(echo "$@" | wc -c)
    line=$(for i in `seq 0 $input_char`; do printf "-"; done)
    # tput This should be the best option. what tput does is it will
    # read the terminal info and render the correctly escaped ANSI code
    # for you.
    # Code like \033[31m will break the readline library in some of the
    # terminals.
    tput bold
    line="$(tput setaf 3)${line}"
    space=${line//-/ }
    echo " ${line}"
    printf '|' ; echo -n "$space" ; printf "%s\n" '|';
    printf '| ' ;tput setaf 4; echo -n "$@"; tput setaf 3 ; printf "%s\n" ' |';
    printf '|' ; echo -n "$space" ; printf "%s\n" '|';
    echo " ${line}"
    tput sgr 0
}

box_out $@
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As your shebang and syntax indicates unportable `bash`, I prefer it this way:

```sh
function box_out()
{
  local s="$*"
  tput setaf 3
  echo " -${s//?/-}-
| ${s//?/ } |
| $(tput setaf 4)$s$(tput setaf 3) |
| ${s//?/ } |
 -${s//?/-}-"
  tput sgr 0
}
```

Of course, you can optimize it if you wish.

**Update** as requested in comment, to handle multiline text too.

```sh
function box_out()
{
  local s=("$@") b w
  for l in "${s[@]}"; do
    ((w<${#l})) && { b="$l"; w="${#l}"; }
  done
  tput setaf 3
  echo " -${b//?/-}-
| ${b//?/ } |"
  for l in "${s[@]}"; do
    printf '| %s%*s%s |\n' "$(tput setaf 4)" "-$w" "$l" "$(tput setaf 3)"
  done
  echo "| ${b//?/ } |
 -${b//?/-}-"
  tput sgr 0
}
```

Call it with multiple parameters, like `box_out 'first line' 'more line' 'even more line'`.

Comment: Awesome.............. You are Master ....

Comment: How would I apply this function to multiple lines, or a single line with `\n` type CRs?

Comment: @manatwork that's marvelous, BUT... it's not working for expanding variables...and then if I try any quoting to resolve, it prints on one line again. Thank you so much for the quick response and brilliant solution!

Comment: Variable expansion should occur _before_ the box_out function being executed. Double quotes and escapes should still work as usual: http://pastebin.com/ekmUKUkn By the way, you also use `bash`, right?

Comment: It was the double quotes that did it! AMAZING :D

Comment: Would you please either provide a link or explain how this works? There is a lot of "magic" in there: `${s[@]}`, `((w<${#l}))`, `${b//?/-}`.

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman: `${s[@]}` – all elements of [array](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) s; `((w<${#l}))` – `((`..`))` [shell arithmetic](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) testing whether variable w's value is less than variable l value's length, obtained with [parameter expansion](https://gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) (`#` – string length); `${b//?/-}` – parameter expansion replacing all occurrences of any character with a “-” (`//` – replace all; `?` – wildcard meaning any character).

Answer (score 14):

So, my solution is not *quite* the same as yours, but strictly speaking it prints a box around the text, and the implementation is a bit simpler so I thought I'd share.

```
banner() {
    msg="# $* #"
    edge=$(echo "$msg" | sed 's/./#/g')
    echo "$edge"
    echo "$msg"
    echo "$edge"
}
```

And here it is in action:

```
$ banner "hi"
######
# hi #
######
$ banner "hi there"
############
# hi there #
############
```

Just plain text, no fancy ansi colors or anything.

Comment: I like simplicity of this solution :).

Answer (score 12):

## [**Boxes!**](http://boxes.thomasjensen.com/)

```
$ echo 'Love Unix & Linux' | boxes -d stone -p a2v1
+---------------------+
|                     |
|  Love Unix & Linux  |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

Since `boxes` requires text to be sent to it as a file, I recommend using the syntax in the above example where the text is piped into `boxes` through `echo`.

### "Why `boxes`?"

Using it is easy. Just tell it what border design you want to use and how you want it to appear, and you're done.

Of course if you want to be creative, you can make your own designs. It's really easy and fun to do.  The only drawback with using `boxes` is that I haven't figured out how to center a box generated with `boxes` to align center with the screen, though there is a bash hack for that

### "What about color?"

The original question had demonstrated the use of color codes.  So it only seems right to show how `boxes` would handle this.

While `tput` is popular, I consider myself an old school Bash person and still like using the escape commands. I'm sure there are a few folks here at StackExchange that would argue against it, but to each their own.  Regardless, I am willing to set aside my personal preference of doing this to include another example doing it the `tput` way.

Naturally, I think the first step is to set the color of the inside text. So let's do that first.

```
printf "$(tput setaf 4)Love Unix & Linux$(tput sgr 0)" | boxes -d stone -p a2v1
+---------------------------------+
|                                 |
|  Love Unix & Linux  |
|                                 |
+---------------------------------+
```

If this were in the terminal, `Love Unix & Linux` would be blue...however as you can see, `boxes` did not handle this well.  So what wen't wrong?

```
printf "$(tput setaf 4)Love Unix & Linux$(tput sgr 0)" | boxes -d stone -p a2v1 | cat -A
+---------------------------------+$
|                                 |$
|  ^[[34mLove Unix & Linux^[(B^[[0m  |$
|                                 |$
+---------------------------------+$
```

A closer inspection by showing the hidden characters with `cat -A` shows `boxes` assumed the length of the box to include the length of text AND the escape characters.

It should be noted though, that if you use a program like [`lolcat`](https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat/) *outside* of `boxes`, the output looks like this

```
$ echo 'Love Unix & Linux' | boxes -d stone -p a2v1 | lolcat -f
+---------------------+
|                     |
|  Love Unix & Linux  |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

but with the box and text in rainbow colors.

It's a good thing I hadn't made my own border designs that included color codes in them as of yet, as I would imagine the border designs would be fallable to the same problems.

### Centering Text, ASCII Art, and BOXES!!!

<s>The other flaw `boxes` has is that if you know how to use Bash to center text to the with of the terminal, `boxes` will still align the box to the left of the screen.</s> Figured it out.

When you want to center text that is not in a box, you can simply use

```
center(){
  COLS=$(tput cols)  # use the current width of the terminal.
  printf "%*s\n" "$(((${#1}+${COLS})/2))" "$1"
}
```

And use that to center a single line of text.

```
center 'Love Unix & Linux'
```

For ascii-art where multiple lines are used and must be fixed in place there is this option.

```
# Rather than removing text, even things out by padding lines with spaces
draw_banner(){
  local banner="$1"
  # Banner Width
  BW=$(cat $banner | awk '{print length}' | sort -nr | head -1)

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=$(echo "${line}" | sed -n -e 's/^  / /g;p')
    line=$(printf "%-${BW}s" "${line}")
    center "${line}"  # our center function from earlier.
  done < "$banner"
}

draw_banner "path/to/your_ascii_art_logo.txt"
```

But if you like to use things like `figlet`, you don't need to use those functions as the `-c` option provides an option to center.

```
$figfontdir="path/to/figlet/fonts"
$figfont="Alligator"
text_banner(){
  COLS=$(tput cols)  # use the width of the terminal!
  figlet -d "$figfontdir" -f "$figfont" -k -w $COLS -c "$1"
}

text_banner 'Love Unix & Linux'
```

For `boxes`, we do something similar to `draw_banner()` but we need to pipe the data!

```
# Center a box created with `boxes
# It's like draw_banner, but `<<<` reads a string of data rather than a file.
$boxfile="/path/to/your_box_designs.box" # or ".txt". I like ".box".
$boxdesgin="stone"
center_box(){
  local data="$(</dev/stdin)"  # Read from standard input
  # Banner Width
  BW=$(cat <<< ${data} | awk '{print length}' | sort -nr | head -1)

  while IFS= read -r line; do
    line=$(echo "${line}" | sed -n -e 's/^  / /g;p')
    line=$(printf "%-${BW}s" "${line}")
    center "${line}"  # our center command from earlier.
  done <<< "${data}"
}

(
 # A bunch of stuff to center!
) | boxes -f $boxfile -d $boxdesign -a hcvcjc | center_box
```

### Outstanding issues

Fixing <s>both of these issues</s> the UTF/ANSI character issue would not only make `boxes` a better solution to encapsulating text in an ASCII box, but allow for a creative alternative that could be called upon instead of hand-coding boxes.

Comment: One other thing I should mention: If you install `lolcat` **DO NOT** install it through `apt-get`, install it as a `gem` through Ruby.  The Ruby gem version is newer and respects ANSI box characters.

Answer (score 1):

Took @robru comment and improved it a bit to allow multi line text.

```
  function PP () {
  local longest=0
  local string_array=("${@}")
  for i in "${string_array[@]}"; do
    if [[ "${#i}" -gt "${longest}" ]]; then
      local longest=${#i}
      local longest_line="${i}" # Longest line
    fi
  done

  local edge=$(echo "$longest_line" | sed 's/./#/g' | sed 's/^#/###/' | sed 's/#$/###/')
  local middle_edge=$(echo "$longest_line" | sed 's/./\ /g' | sed 's/^\ /#\  /' | sed 's/\ $/\ \ #/')

  echo -e "\n${edge}"
  echo "${middle_edge}"

  for i in "${string_array[@]}"; do
    local length_i=${#i}
    local length_ll="${#longest_line}"
    if [[ "${length_i}" -lt "${length_ll}"  ]]; then
            printf "# "
            local remaining_spaces=$((length_ll-length_l))
            printf "${i}"
            while [[ ${remaining_spaces} -gt ${#i} ]]; do
                    printf " "
                    local remaining_spaces=$((remaining_spaces-1))
            done
            printf " #\n"
    else
      echo "# ${i} #"
    fi
  done

  echo "${middle_edge}"
  echo -e "${edge}\n"
}
```

So, If you write `PP "Hi." "I'm Here"  "Nice to meet you......"`
You'll  get the following:

```
##########################
#                        #
# Hi.                    #
# I'm Here               #
# Nice to meet you...... #
#                        #
##########################
```

Comment: Well, the beauty of robru’s answer was its elegant simplicity.  You have added a lot of complexity without even matching the functionality of manatwork’s answer.  And your function has a bug: try `PP avoid %s`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I just very recently used [manatwork's multi-line box answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70616/502849) in my project, I modded it to where it can creates banners made of - with centered text, no edges and even take BASH color parameters (with an optional second one that changes the color of the text). I created labels for every bash color I want to use through my project (i.e. RED='\e[31m')

```
# Multi line banners are generated like `banner ${COLOR} ${OPTIONAL_SECONDCOLOR} "first line" "second line" "third line"`
function banner() {
    local s=("${@:3}") b w
    local second_color=$2
    if [[ ! "$second_color" =~ "\e[".* ]]; then #If the second color isn't declared, then make the function use only the first color declared
        local s=("${@:2}") b w
        local second_color=$1
    fi

    for l in "${s[@]}"; do
        ((w<${#l})) && { b="         $l         "; w="${#l}"; }
    done
    echo -ne $1
    echo "-${b//?/-}-"
    for l in "${s[@]}"; do
        printf '         %s%*s%s         \n' "$(echo -ne $second_color)" "-$w" "$l" "$(echo -ne $1)"
    done
    echo -e "-${b//?/-}-${NC}"
}
```

Example usage:

```
banner ${LIGHT_PURPLE} "test here something line 1. SUPER LONG AND IT REALLY NEEDS TO BE LONG" "super duper long line 2" # Single Color option
banner ${LIGHT_PURPLE} ${RED} " This should be red now test here something line 1. SUPER LONG AND IT REALLY NEEDS TO BE LONG" "super duper long line 2" #Two Color Option
```

Results from code:
[image: The result from the banner code]